# Do clerics and Imams qualify for Nikah mut‘ah (temporary pleasure marriages)?

Tags: nikah

I was just wondering if it was acceptable amongst those that preach [Nikah mut‘ah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nikah_mut%E2%80%98ah) to themselves get them? In Catholicism priests are forbidden to accept a wife because it blurs their total allegiance to God.

- Can an Islamic Imam get married?
- Are they premitted pleasure marriages?

Answer (score 2):

Islamic law doesn't really differentiate between leaders and laymen; what is legal for one is legal for all, and what is illegal for one is illegal for all.  So there is nothing preventing an Imam from getting married like anyone else, be it a regular marriage or even nikah mut'ah (for those schools that permit it).